# Unable to plot pie chart in Dojo

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid, dojox.charting

I am trying to plot pie chart in dojo for a POC. I am not able to draw it. Can someone help me to figure out the issue. I googled lot but couldn't find exact issue.

I am able to draw bar chart but seeing issues with pie chart. I am storing data in dojo store and converting into series and providing to pie graph but ending up seeing nothing.

I will be so grateful if someone help me to figure out the issue.

Below is my code :

```js
<script>
    var geoData = {
      identifier: 'Id',
      label: 'Id',
      items: [{
        Id: '1',
        Name: 'Africa',
        Age: 10,
        Gender: 'Male',
        Area: "Java",
        Experience: 1
      }, {
        Id: '2',
        Name: 'Asia1',
        Age: 45,
        Gender: 'Male',
        Area: "C",
        Experience: 3
      }, {
        Id: '3',
        Name: 'Asia2',
        Age: 35,
        Gender: 'Male',
        Area: "Java",
        Experience: 2
      }, {
        Id: '4',
        Name: 'Asia3',
        Age: 23,
        Gender: 'Male',
        Area: "C",
        Experience: 1
      }, {
        Id: '5',
        Name: 'Asia4',
        Age: 78,
        Gender: 'Male',
        Area: "Perl",
        Experience: 4
      }]
    };

    var layoutGeo = [
      [{
        field: "Id",
        name: "Id",
        width: 10
      }, {
        field: "Name",
        name: "Name",
        width: 10,
        editable: true
      }, {
        field: "Age",
        name: "Age",
        width: 10,
        editable: true
      }, {
        field: "Gender",
        name: "Gender",
        width: 10,
        editable: true,
        type: "dojox.grid.cells.Select",
        options: ["Male", "Female"]
      }, {
        field: "Area",
        name: "Area",
        width: 10,
        editable: true
      }, {
        field: "Experience",
        name: "Experience",
        width: 10,
        editable: true
      }]
    ];

    function plotPieChart() {
      dojo.empty("peiDiv");

      // Create the chart within it's "holding" node
      var pieChart = new dojox.charting.Chart2D("peiDiv");

      // Set the theme
      pieChart.setTheme(dojox.charting.themes.Claro);

      // Add the only/default plot
      pieChart.addPlot("default", {
        type: "Pie",
        radius: 200,
        fontColor: "black",
        labelOffset: 20
      });

      var series = makeseries(geoData);

      // Add the series of data
      pieChart.addSeries("Area", series);

      // Render the chart!
      pieChart.render();
    }

    function makeseries(data) {
      return [{
        datapoints: "items",
        field: "Id",
        name: "Id"
      }, {
        datapoints: "items",
        field: "Name",
        name: "Name"
      }, {
        datapoints: "items",
        field: "Area",
        name: "Area"
      }];
    }
    </script>
```

```html
  </head>
  <body class="claro">
    <div data-dojo-type="dojo/data/ItemFileWriteStore" data-dojo-props="data:geoData" data-dojo-id="geoStore" columnreordering="true"></div>
    <b>Set the population to assign to all items</b><br>
    <div id="grid" 
    data-dojo-type="dojox/grid/DataGrid"
    data-dojo-props="store:geoStore,
    structure:layoutGeo,
    query:{},
    queryOptions:{'deep':true},
    rowsPerPage:40">
  </div>
  <div display:inline-block>
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" data-dojo-id="Add">Add</div>
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" data-dojo-id="Remove">Remove</div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div display:inline-block>
    <div id="chartDiv" style="width: 400px; height: 250px;"></div>
    <br>
    <div id="peiDiv" style="width: 400px; height: 250px;"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Let me know if you want me to provide more details. Please don't do negative voting as i need immediate response. It will not get much user attention is voted negatively

Comment: what does the dev tools console say? Any errors? I would suggest making a jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com to make it easier for people to see what is up.

Comment: This jsfiddle url : http://jsfiddle.net/rajeevprasanna/4EGnu/5/
This code is showing grid locally but not in jsfiddle

Comment: Here's a tidied jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tupton/u9UjY/. I cleaned up your HTML a little bit and formatted things in the correct section for jsfiddle.

Comment: Hey @ThomasUpton, I am so thankful for your kind help. I was blocked completely on converting store data into series. Your help saved my day. Thank you once again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `makeseries` function isn't returning data in the format that a pie chart can use. [Take a look at the example in the documentation here](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/charting/#highlighter_460928). If, for example, you wanted to plot a pie chart of the ages in `geoData`, `makeseries` should be something like the following:

```
function makeseries(data) {
    return data.items.map(function(d) {
        return {x: d['Id'], y: d['Age']};
    });
}
```

[Here's a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tupton/u9UjY/) showing that in the context of your original code. It looks like you'll also have to resize the pie chart's containing div.

Comment: Hey thomas, i am looking for plotting a graph area vs no of epmoyees in that area in pie chart. How can i achieve this

Comment: You would need to map your data correctly. Loop through all your items  and store the count for each area in an object, then return an array with something like `{x:1, y:area_counts[area]}` for each area. There are probably a number of questions that answer how to do that on this site.

Comment: I've updated [my original jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tupton/u9UjY/) to something along the lines of what you were talking about.

Comment: Thanks a lot. whatever i say, it is very less to convey my gratitude for your help. For past 3hours, i am struggling with this. Thinking of finding a simple dojo plugin but couldn't find any. We need to convert data on our own ?

Comment: One last question, How to add labels to pie chart area name like java, c etc

Comment: I got solution by providing text:value as other parameter